# concatenate excel datas with python or Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

Here's my problem, I have an Excel sheet with 2 columns (see below)[image]

I'd like to print (on python console or in a excel cell) all the data under this form :

```
 "1" : ["1123","1165", "1143", "1091", "n"], *** n ∈ [A2; A205]***
```

We don't really care about the Column B. But I need to add every postal code under this specific form.

is there a way to do it with Excel or in Python with Panda ? (If you have any other ideas I would love to hear them)

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `parse_cols` for parse first column and then filter out all columns from 205 to 1000 by `skiprows` in [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html):

```
df = pd.read_excel('test.xls', 
                   sheet_name='Sheet1', 
                   parse_cols=0, 
                   skiprows=list(range(205,1000)))
print (df)
```

Last use [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html) for convert first column to `list`:

```
print({"1": df.iloc[:,0].tolist()})
```

---

The simpliest solution is parse only first column and then use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = pd.read_excel('test.xls', 
                   parse_cols=0)

print({"1": df.iloc[:206,0].astype(str).tolist()})
```

Comment: I see erorr, so I add another simplier solution, please check it.

Comment: Yes that's a really good idea ! There is just the " " missing between every postal code : "1" : ["1123","1165", "1143", "1091", "n"]. Do you have any ideas ? It's quite important because I used this form for Javascript

Comment: Yes, give me a sec.

Comment: I edit answer, you need only cast to `str` by `astype(str)`

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with excel, but pandas could easily handle this problem.

First, read the excel to a DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(filename)
```

Then, print as you like

```
print({"1": list(df.iloc[0:N]['A'])})
```

where `N` is the amount you would like to print. That is it. If the list is not a string list, you need to cast the int to string.

Also, there are a lot parameters that can control the load part of excel `read_excel`, you can go through the document to set suitable parameters.

Hope this would be helpful to you.

Comment: I have an Big error which say :
File "pandas\index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4066)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 161, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:3995)
KeyError: 'A'

Comment: Check your column names `df.columns`. Make sure you use the correct name. Actually you can also use `df.iloc[0:N][1]` to slice dataframe with rows=[0:N] and cols=[1]. More over, check documents of pandas, to see how to select rows and cols in dataframe [Indexing and Selecting data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html).